# Run function on schedule not from menu item

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script which has been cobbled together.

It creates a new menu item in my sheet entitled 'WordPress'.  Within my sheet, I can then click the menu item, and choose GET POSTS.  Which executes the full function perfectly.

However, instead of being a menu item in my sheet which need manual action, I would like to have this run on a schedule via the sheduler.

Can anyone advise how I can activate the sheet called WordPress, and run the function on that sheet, rather than having to manually open the sheet?

```
function onOpen() {
  // setup a custom menu
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() 
      .createMenu('WordPress')
      .addItem('Get Posts', 'getPosts')
      .addToUi();
  setupSheet();
}


function setupSheet() {
  // just clear sheet and set & style headings
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();



  // set the tab to post - just for neatness
 var sheetname = ss.getSheets()[0].setName('Posts');
  // clear the sheet
 var range = ss.getDataRange();
 range.clear();
 //set headings
  ss.getRange('A1').setValue('Featured Image');
  ss.getRange('B1').setValue('Title');
  ss.getRange('C1').setValue('Updated');
  ss.getRange('D1').setValue('Post URL');
  
  ss.getRange('A1:D1').setFontWeight('bold');
  ss.getRange('A1:D1').setFontStyle('italic');

}


//this version of the function just gets a single post (the most recent)
function getPosts(){
  setupSheet();
  // loop here as we need get back posts in chunks, Rest API max is 100 post
  offset = 0;
  per_page = 1;
  while ( (got=getPage(offset,per_page)) > 0  && (got=getPage(offset,per_page)) < 2  ) {
    
    offset+=got;
    Logger.log('offset %s', offset);
  }
}

function getPage(offset,per_page) {
  // gets posts in chunks of per_page
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();  // used for error messages
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  
  var options = {
      'method': 'get',
      "contentType" : "application/json",
      'muteHttpExceptions': true
    }
  var apiHost = 'https://mywebsite.co.uk';   // set to your own domain
  url = apiHost + '/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?per_page='+per_page+'&offset='+offset;
  
  try {
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
    var data = JSON.parse(response)
    // loop through the map and output to sheet
    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {  
     row=offset+i+2;  // set the row to make sure it is below header and takes into account the paging
     ss.getRange('A'+row).setValue(data[i].featured_image_url);
     ss.getRange('B'+row).setValue(data[i].title.rendered);
     ss.getRange('C'+row).setValue(data[i].modified);
    ss.getRange('D'+row).setValue(data[i].link);
  }
    return data.length;
  } catch(error) {
    var result = ui.alert( error.toString());
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

change this: `while ( (got=getPage(offset,per_page)) > 0  && (got=getPage(offset,per_page)) < 2  ) {`

to this: `while ( (got==getPage(offset,per_page)) > 0  && (got==getPage(offset,per_page)) < 2  ) {`

Also you cannot run UI when running a function from a trigger because there is no user interface.

Comment: Within that code I cant see any mention of the sheet name?

Comment: I'm just pointing out an error in your code.  It may not be the only error.  But perhaps your problem is that you [mcve] is not focused enough to insure that you get the answer you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Just go to Triggers in the script editor (on the left, looks like a clock) and make a time-based trigger for it. Have you tried that already?

Comment: yeah, tried that....it runs, but nothing happens in the sheet.

Comment: Give us a link to the sheet?